# Are email, address, and phone scope types supported in AdalJS/openid/oauth2?

Tags: azure, openid, oauth-2.0, adal.js

I am using the [AdalJS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) v1.0.8 library to authorize users against an Azure AD endpoint, and was wondering if the `&scope` types for `email`, `address`, and `phone` are supported in AdalJS/openid/oauth2.

My authorization endpoint URL:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id={client id}&redirect_uri={my redirect uri}&state=2af81ff1-89ca-4f23-825d-ca29177c3df5&client-request-id=2f82e417-630b-4318-88ed-c35103046249&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.7&nonce=4c03cbca-03b2-4a53-acc6-1177f499969a&prompt=login&scope=openid+profile+email+address+phone

After the login page appears and the user enters their credentials, the token comes back successfully and I can see the user's `profile` object when calling `AuthenticationContext.getCachedUser()`. However, I do not see `email`, `address`, or `phone` information being returned even [though these scope types](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#Scopes) are requested in the `&scope` query string parameter.

[image: AuthenticationContext.getCachedUser results]
[image: Profile object]

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the `profile` object. You might find the additional information in there.

```
{
   "sub": "248289761001",
   "name": "Jane Doe",
   "given_name": "Jane",
   "family_name": "Doe",
   "preferred_username": "j.doe",
   "email": "janedoe@example.com",
   "picture": "http://example.com/janedoe/me.jpg"
}
```

Comment: My `profile` object is a little different than yours, but does not contain the additional information.

Comment: Can you post an image of it please.

Comment: I added it to my original question (see above).

Comment: @Sandy Hmm. You have asked a fantastic question. When I have more time then I intend to look into it further for you.